# Clicking YouTube links with Selenium for java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to click on the first link of a youtube search using selenium. I am storing a song name and artist from a user, searching for this song on Youtube using the code `search.sendKeys(title+" by "+artist+" official music video"); search.sendKeys("\n");` where search is the previously located search box. At this point I have a list of youtube video links and want to select the first one regardless of search criteria. The problem im having at this point is I can't find any searchBy criteria that applies to the first link of any search.

Comment: is there a code that you have tried so far ?

Comment: Its a very generic question, expect you to show some code that you have tried or the steps you followed. Having said that, I have given you a solution outline, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is very generic, i believe the steps that you are trying to do is launch youtube, search for a something say "selenium" and click on the first video. This is the solution that i came up with, there can be multiple solutions.

1. Launch youtube by `driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")`
2. Search for "Selenium in searchbox. (I will leave this to you)
3. To search for the first link I am using javascript executer, `document.querySelector(".style-scope ytd-video-renderer").innerText` , this would give the following output

   11:37:39
   NOW PLAYING
   Selenium Full Course - Learn Selenium in 12 Hours | Selenium Tutorial For Beginners | Edureka
   503K views
   1 year ago
   edureka!
   #edureka #seleniumEdureka #seleniumFullCourse #seleniumWebdriver #seleniumAutomationTesting #SeleniumTutorial ...
4. Now from the above step you can get the video title, store it in some String variable  (say we store it as `String videoTitle`)
5. now run the xpath to click on the link with the above video title `//yt-formatted-string[contains(text(),'+videoTitle+')]`

Comment: Sorry for the very generic question. I have revised my original question and hopefully this makes it easier to answer.

Comment: Its the same solution that I have provided. Have you tried the JavascriptExecutor solution that i provided above?